# Date form element

Tags: datetime

I am using the following code.

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  // Creating the date/time element starts here.

  // Provide a default date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
  $date = '2008-12-31 00:00:00';

  // Provide a format using regular PHP format parts (see documentation on php.net).
  // If you're using a date_select, the format will control the order of the date parts in the selector,
  // rearrange them any way you like. Parts left out of the format will not be displayed to the user.
  $format = 'Y-m-d H:i';

  $form['date2'] = array(
     '#type' => 'date_select', // types 'date_popup', 'date_text' and 'date_timezone' are also supported. See .inc file.
     '#title' => t('Date'),
     '#default_value' => $date, 
     '#date_format' => $format,
     '#date_label_position' => 'within', // See other available attributes and what they do in date_api_elements.inc
     '#date_timezone' => 'America/Chicago', // Optional, if your date has a timezone other than the site timezone.
     '#date_increment' => 15, // Optional, used by the date_select and date_popup elements to increment minutes and seconds.
     '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3', // Optional, used to set the year range (back 3 years and forward 3 years is the default).
    '#datepicker_options' => array(), // Optional, as of 7.x-2.6+, used to pass in additional parameters from the jQuery Datepicker widget.
  );

  return $form;
}
```

`$form['date2']` is an array that contains a time. I want to use just the year or the day of this array. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, you can change $format to show only the elements you want, so you can do

```
$format = 'Y';
```

to select only the year, and

```
$format = 'd';
```

for the day.